# TypeError: create_node() got an unexpected keyword argument 'client'

Tags: typeerror

I'm trying to connect my node to a host but in the command, I have to put `'client = client'` but it also says

`TypeError: create_node() got an unexpected keyword argument 'client'`

It's just not allowing me to do something that is necessary. I am following a tutorial, does anyone know how to solve this?

Here is a ss of my code.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxZHU.png

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library is built by parsing the JSON so the backend team will need to make that change. It appears the change was unintentional and a fix is in progress.